# Are there axioms for derived functors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $F \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a left exact functor between abelian categories having enough injective objects. We can form the right derived functor $RF \colon D^+(\mathcal{A}) \to D(\mathcal{B})$ which can be defined in different ways. In Weibel's *Introduction to homological algebra* for example, $RF$ is defined (up to equivalence) as the functor admitting "the most general" natural transformation $q_\mathcal{B} \circ F \Rightarrow RF \circ q_\mathcal{A}$ with respect to
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K^+(\mathcal{A}) @>F>> K(\mathcal{B})\\
@V q_\mathcal{A} VV @VV q_\mathcal{B} V\\
D^+(\mathcal{A}) @>>RF> D(\mathcal{B})
\end{CD}$$

This definition is certainly nice for constructing morphism between functors. I wonder however whether $RF$ can also be described by properties which are more relevant for computational purposes. For example, the following properties seem really useful for computations:

- $F$ is the zeroth cohomology of $RF$. More precisely, we have $F \cong H^0 \circ RF \circ j$, where $j \colon \mathcal{A} \to D^+(\mathcal{A})$ is the obvious inclusion of categories sending objects of $\mathcal{A}$ to complexes concentrated in degree zero.
- $H^n \circ RF \circ j$ sends all injective objects of $\mathcal{A}$ to zero for all $n \neq 0$.
- $RF$ is a triangulated functor. That is, $RF$ is additive, it commutes with the translation functors, and it sends exact triangles to exact triangles.

What else do I need to know about $RF$ to have it characterized up to equivalence?

Comment: What's wrong with the given definition, as a universally 'general' natural transformation? That is a characterisation. In the only context that I've seen them, derived functors were characterised as Kan extensions. When enough (co)limits exist you can then characterise them by a (co)limit formula

Comment: Since $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injective, I believe that the condition that $H^i(RF(I))=0$ for every injective object $I\in\mathcal{A}$, together with the two conditions you wrote, are enough to characterize $RF$ up to equivalence.

Comment: @FShrike There is nothing wrong with the definition. It just doesn't tell us how to do actual computations (of cohomology groups) with $RF$. We need a list of "axioms" to do so, and I just wonder how a complete list would look like.

Comment: @Roland Good point, this property is certainly missing in my list. I will add it.

Comment: But my point is that a functor which satisfies these three conditions is the derived functor of $F$. You don't need to add anything else.

Comment: @Roland That would be great! Do you have a proof strategy in mind?

Comment: This is somewhat analogous to the fact that $\delta$-functor which vanishes on injectives are universal. In the language of triangulated categories, you will need more machineries though. Use the fact that $K^+(\mathcal{I})\to D^+(\mathcal{A})$ is an equivalence (here $K^+(\mathcal{I})$ is the full subcategories of $K^+(\mathcal{A})$ where the complexes are made of injective objects and that $F(I)\to RF(I)$ is an isomorphism in $D(\mathcal{B})$ for any injective $I$ (this follows from the first two conditions).